# XML attribute change repetitions class name

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have two XML-serializable classes , Parent-Child,imported from Entity Framework. Summarized like this

```cs
[Table("OecPreorden")]
[DataContract]
public partial class OecPreorden
{
    public OecPreorden()
    {
        OecPreordenProductos = new HashSet<OecPreordenProductos>();
    }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, Order = 1, Name = "ProductosComerciales")]
    public virtual ICollection<OecPreordenProductos> OecPreordenProductos { get; set; }
}


[Table("OecPreordenProductos")]
[DataContract]
public class OecPreordenProductos
{
    public OecPreordenProductos()
    {

    }
    [XmlIgnore()]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public long IdPromocion { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public long IdProductoComercial { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public long NroOrden { get; set; }
    public int PreOrden_id { get; set; }
    public virtual OecPreorden OecPreorden { get; set; }
}
```

When I see as XML it is showed like this

```xml
<dir:ProductosComerciales>
  <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
    <dir:OecPreordenProductos>
    <dir:IdPromocion>?</dir:IdPromocion>
    <dir:IdProductoComercial>?</dir:IdProductoComercial>
    <dir:NroOrden>?</dir:NroOrden>
  </dir:OecPreordenProductos>
</dir:ProductosComerciales>
```

As it has zero or more repetitions... it shows the header correct with

```xml
<dir:ProductosComerciales>
```

What i want to change is the header of the iteration..

```xml
<dir:OecPreordenProductos>
```

When i set

```cs
[XmlRoot("AAA")]
public class OecPreordenProductos
```

or

```cs
[XmlType(TypeName = "AAA")]
public class OecPreordenProductos
```

it does not work, it still shows the class name.

How can change the name of repetition class?

Comment: You have to change it in the parent using [XmlElement("AAA")] above the property.

Comment: it does not work.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `[XmlArrayItem("AAA")]` on the OecPreordenProductos-Property:

```
    [Table("OecPreorden")]
        [DataContract]
        public partial class OecPreorden
        {
            public OecPreorden()
            {
                OecPreordenProductos = new HashSet<OecPreordenProductos>();
            }
           [DataMember(IsRequired = false, Order = 1, Name = "ProductosComerciales")]
           [XmlArrayItem("AAA")]
            public virtual ICollection<OecPreordenProductos> OecPreordenProductos { get; set; }
      }
```

Comment: I tested with [XmlArrayItem("AAA")] and it does not work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
[DataMember(IsRequired = false, Order = 1, Name = "ProductosComerciales")]
[XmlArray("OecPreordenProductos")]
[XmlArrayItem("AAA)]
public virtual ICollection<OecPreordenProductos> OecPreordenProductos { get; set; }
```

Comment: What did you get as a label name?  Check the date of the XML file to make sure the date is same as running code.  The change should work.